# Calculate time difference of a Datetime object and get output as floatvalues?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, timedelta

I have a dataframe column of Date and time:

```
0    2017-06-24 08:37:00
1    2017-06-24 08:40:00
2    2017-06-24 08:42:01
3    2017-06-24 08:44:01
4    2017-06-24 08:46:00
5    2017-06-24 08:48:00
6    2017-06-24 08:50:01
7    2017-06-24 08:52:01
8    2017-06-24 08:54:01
9    2017-06-24 08:56:00
10   2017-06-24 08:58:01
11   2017-06-24 09:00:01
12   2017-06-24 09:04:01
13   2017-06-24 09:06:01
Name: Datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I want the time difference of two timestamp such as:

```
2017-06-24 08:40:00 - 2017-06-24 08:37:00 = 3.0

2017-06-24 08:42:01 - 2017-06-24 08:40:00 = 2.1
```

I tried this code:

```
for z in range(len(df)):
    abc = (df["Datetime"].iat[z+1] - df["Datetime"].iat[z])
```

I am getting the output as this with an error:

```
0 days 00:03:00
0 days 00:02:01
0 days 00:02:00
0 days 00:01:59
0 days 00:02:00
0 days 00:02:01
0 days 00:02:00
0 days 00:02:00
0 days 00:01:59
0 days 00:02:01

IndexError: index 14 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 14
```

expected output:

3.0

2.1

2.0

1.59

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you want `range(len(df) - 1)`

Comment: But I want the difference as float.

Comment: You misunderstand. I believe you are getting an out of range error because you are running a `for` loop across `df` using its length as a max index. But `df`'s length is 14, and its max index is 13. So in the `for` loop you need to adjust the range as I've shown above.

Comment: The thing is you have two problems here: 1) The output isn't in the format you want. 2) You're getting an out of range exception. For problem 1, see Jezrael's answer. For problem 2, apply the fix I've given

Comment: Understood. Thanks Jack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) - output is `timedelta`s, so need convert by [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and if need output in minutes divide by `60`:

```
df['diff'] = df['Datetime'].diff().dt.total_seconds().div(60)
print (df)
              Datetime      diff
0  2017-06-24 08:37:00       NaN
1  2017-06-24 08:40:00  3.000000
2  2017-06-24 08:42:01  2.016667
3  2017-06-24 08:44:01  2.000000
4  2017-06-24 08:46:00  1.983333
5  2017-06-24 08:48:00  2.000000
6  2017-06-24 08:50:01  2.016667
7  2017-06-24 08:52:01  2.000000
8  2017-06-24 08:54:01  2.000000
9  2017-06-24 08:56:00  1.983333
10 2017-06-24 08:58:01  2.016667
11 2017-06-24 09:00:01  2.000000
12 2017-06-24 09:04:01  4.000000
13 2017-06-24 09:06:01  2.000000
```

Comment: Can i use same logic for average on float objects?

Comment: Do you think `difference` ? Then use `df['diff'] = df['float_col'].diff()`

Comment: No, i want to calculate the average of a column of a dataframe but the logic should be like your this solution. take first two elements and calculate average, like this?

Comment: Hmmm, it seems you need `df['diff'] = df['float_col'].rolling(2).mean()`

Comment: I got one more question. If I want to calculate the difference of first and last timestamp of the same date and get a float value. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Without data hard answer, but it seems need `df = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)['date'].apply(lambda x: x.iat[0] - x.iat[-1])` should work.

Comment: can you please look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461346/append-series-to-dict-or-list-or-dataframe-from-for-loop