# Append series to dict or list or dataframe from for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, series

I have created a for loop which gives an out like this:

```
       SSTIME
SCODE        
0           0
1          57
3         202
```

I did reset_index on this series and i got this:

```
   SCODE  SSTIME
0      0       0
1      1      57
2      3     202
```

I want to append each result into a dataframe which will have column of scode and sstime.

P.S: SCODE can be of different length.

My objective is to create a Dataframe from that results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need not reset_index, but [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) of `list of Series`:

```
list_ser = []
#sample loop for crate Series
for x in L:
    s = create_function()
    list_ser.append(s)

df = pd.concat(list_ser)
```

Comment: ,i am not able to append the results in the dataframe.

Comment: Can you add some another Series to question? Becuase this should works.

Comment: this is working but column names are also appending everytime.

Comment: Also how do you generate Series? In some loop?

Comment: Sorry, `axis=1` not need, because 2 columns output.

Comment: Can you please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250731/split-dataframes-in-groups-and-sub-groups-and-store-the-output-as-csv

Answer (score 0):

You can convert each of these dataframes to a dictionary with `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict()`

And afterwards add to a list:

```
result = []
for x in range(1,13):
    result.append(x)
```